# Cemented or concreted?

Tags: verbs

I've been asked to send out a memo that contains the phrase:

> Joe has further concreted his status...

and I think it looks odd. I want to change it to *cemented*, but I'm a Brit living in Texas and maybe *concreted* is the correct usage here! Thoughts?

Comment: Cemented is the common verb. But that's not cast in concrete.

Comment: *Concreted* sounds more firm than *cemented*. But it's certainly not as common.

Comment: There's a technical difference.  "Cemented" means pretty much the same as "glued".  "Concreted" means that various fragments have been fit together into a single solid piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OED has the verb:

> 3. transitive. To render concrete. Also reflexive.
>
> 1654   R. Whitlock Ζωοτομία 389   When by incorrigiblenesse Sins be concreted into Sinners, and they become even all one.
>
> 1884   G. Allen Philistia II. xxii. 249   Don't be so abstract, Ernest; concrete yourself a little.
>
> 1938   T. Wesseling Liturgy & Life i. 5   The whole reason of existence of any product whatever is therefore to realize, to concrete the purpose of the producer.

Although the quote is a little strange as once something is concrete, it is hard to see how it can be further concreted...

Comment: I think maybe that's why it looks odd - very tempted to remove "further"...